# RabbitMQ issue in AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a queue in rabbitMQ server(version 3.3.5), on which 1 publisher publishes the messages. I have 1 consumer, which listens to those messages. Sometimes, the consumer stops receiving the messages published on the queue. This does not happen in development environment. But, it happens in testing environment.
The type of exchange used is topic exchange.
Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's in the logs? maybe it is a `heartbeat` configuration .

Comment: From logs, I can see, that producer is able to publish messages on the queue. But, consumer is not receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a similar question like this has been asked, the cause was invariably that the consumer thread is "stuck" in user code (your listener or something downstream of it) somewhere.

When the consumer thread is held up in user code, it can no longer receive messages.

When the system gets into this state, you need to take a thread dump (with jstack, visualvm, etc) to find out what the container thread is doing.